# Как сделать такую проверку на JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция которая выполняется при загрузке страницы( всех страниц сайтов)
Если пользователь перезагружает страницу или переходит со страницы на страницу то скрипт выполняется.
Как сделать что бы скрипт выполнялся лишь тогда когда пользователь открывает браузер. Т.е если он закрыл браузер и снова зайдет - скрипт выполниться, если же он перейдет на другую страницу либо же обновит текущею - скрипт не должен выполняться

Comment: Так добавьте переменную в localStorage/Cookie и проверяйте, был ли пользователь на сайте или нет и в зависимости от варианта выполняйте скрипт

Comment: На самом деле, надежнее выполнять проверки такого рода *на сервере*: используя любую реализацию *keep-alive* запросов, или выдавая пользователям токены с коротким временем жизни (вместо зависимости от переоткрытия браузера, внести зависимость от времени пользователя в состоянии "оффлайн"). Это очень обширная тема, она не "влезет" в ответ...

Comment: Речь о сайте или о браузерном расширении?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

События "открытия браузера" не существует, но можно попробовать реализовать проверку через установку флага в сессионных куках (когда параметры `Expires` и `Max-age` не указаны в куке, она называется *session cookie*, так как живет только до закрытия браузера).

Хоть браузеры и могут применять восстановление сессий (делая их "вечными"), более надежного способа вроде нет.
Так что, в качестве подстраховки, желательно явно сбрасывать такой флаг в куках (по какому-либо другому условию), если есть такая возможность.

---

MDN: [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie):

> If neither `expires` nor `max-age` specified it will expire at the end of session.
>
> > When user privacy is a concern, It is important that any web app implementation will invalidate cookie data after a certain timeout and won't rely on the browser clearing session cookies
> >     One of the most beloved features of Firefox prevents session cookies from ever expiring.
> >     The same issue is also occuring with google chrome (and probably with other browsers offering similar features)

---

**p.s.**: А `sessionStorage` не подходит, так как оно воспринимает новой сессией открытие новой вкладки / нового окна с тем же сайтом :(